# Centering an image in a navigation pane

Tags: html, css, nav

So I'm new to html/css and this website, but I'm having trouble laying out my style sheet for my page. 
this is a picture of my navigation pane: https://i.stack.imgur.com/88rwB.png
I'm wanting to center the pictures (which also belong to a hyperlinked list) but no matter how many techniques I try, I can't seem to figure out how.

This is my nav css:

```html
nav {
 display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; 
 font-size:12px;
 color: #ffffff; 
 text-align:center;
 line-height:30px;
    background-color:#68594c;
    height:778px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px; 
}
nav img
 { vertical-align: center; }
nav ul{
 list-style-type:none;
 }
```

this is my html:

```html
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="home 3.html"><img src="images/home.png" alt="Home"></a></li>
<li><a href="Menu.html"><img src="images/menu.png" alt="Menu"></a></li>
<li><a href="Blank.html"><img src="images/blank.png" alt="Blank"></a></li>
<li><a href="Blank.html"><img src="images/blanktwo.png" alt="Blank"></a></li>
<li><a href="Blank.html"><img src="images/blank.png" alt="Blank"></a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

I tried

```html
nav img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

but it didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a link to the website? I'm guessing you want to center the images horizontally within the brown background?

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure how to link the website as its just an html file on my computer at the moment. I'm wanting the images to sit in the center of the brown. http://i.stack.imgur.com/k8thl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the padding and set `text-align: center;` to the ul it will center the images

Checkout my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZObXO

Answer (score 0):

By default, most browsers give `ul` elements a left padding. You should be able to say:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You should also remove the `vertical-align: center` from the `nav img`, since that's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I am submitting my answer using the image you posted in the comments as a basis: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8thl.png

Here is a jsfiddle where you can see my code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/4kgjw11s/

Your HTML code is unchanged but I have made changes to the CSS:

```
nav {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; 
  font-size:12px;
  color: #ffffff; 
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  background-color:#68594c;
  height:778px;
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  padding:0px; 
}
nav > ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type:none;
}
nav > ul > li {
  text-align: right;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  margin-right: -25px;
}
nav > ul > li > a >img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

The image dimensions are placeholders, when you replace them with your real image sizes take the `width`, divide it by 2, then set it as a negative `margin-right` for `nav > ul > li > a`